# unable to disconnect from postgres database using sequel gem

Tags: ruby, postgresql, sequel

I've just started using the Sequel rubygem, and it appears that the 'disconnect' method isn't working. Here is the output from my IRB test session:

```
1.9.3-p194 :002 > require 'sequel'
 => true 
1.9.3-p194 :003 > DB = Sequel.connect('postgres://postgres:mypassword@my_pg_host:5432/my_db')
 => #<Sequel::Postgres::Database: "postgres://postgres:mypassword@my_pg_host:5432/my_db"> 
1.9.3-p194 :004 > DB.test_connection
 => true 
1.9.3-p194 :005 > DB.disconnect
 => [] 
1.9.3-p194 :006 > DB.test_connection
 => true
```

I don't see anything in the Sequel documentation that indicates why this wouldn't work:

http://sequel.rubyforge.org/rdoc/classes/Sequel/Database.html#method-i-disconnect

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DB.disconnect` disconnects all connections currently in the connection pool, and removes the connections from the pool.  Calling `DB.test_connection` afterward will look in the connection pool for a connection, and since the pool is empty, will cause a new connection to be created.

The code you post is completely expected behavior, but I'm guessing you were not aware that `DB` does not represent a single connection to the database.